# Something is going wrong while placing values into array, Sum of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Basically, the program given to me is to add the sum of the array's rows and columns and give it back into the same array

if **m = 3 , n = 4**

Eg:

> 3    4    5    6 **18**
>
> 1    2    3    4 **10**
>
> 4    3    3    2 **12**
>
> **8** **9** **11** **12**

(The last 12 is the sum of 6 + 4 +2)

So, this is the code for it

```
void summatrix()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<m-1;i++) // m - 1 because total array size is m but values only placed till m-1
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            {
             sum += mat[i][j];
             mat[i][n] = sum; // Pretty sure the problem is here
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of "+ i + " " + (n) + " is "+ sum);

        }
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++) // n-1 beacuse total array size is n, values only placed till n-1
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<m-1;i++)
            {
                sum+=mat[i][j];
                mat[m][j] = sum; // Pretty sure the problem is here
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of "+ (m) + " " + j + " is "+ sum);

        }
        show_mat(); // prints the array
```

Input and output :

```
    The matrix is : 
1 2 3 0 
1 2 3 0 
1 2 3 0 
0 0 0 0 
Sum of 0 4 is 6
Sum of 1 4 is 6
Sum of 2 4 is 6
Sum of 4 0 is 3
Sum of 4 1 is 6
Sum of 4 2 is 9
The matrix is : 
1 2 3 0 
1 2 3 0 
1 2 3 0 
0 0 0 0
```

My printing code:

```
 void show_mat()
    {
        System.out.println("The matrix is : ");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I can post all of my code or anymore whatever is needed if wanted. Sorry if my coding looks bad.. still relatively new to this.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How are you printing the array?

Comment: @manouti I put the code in the original post

Comment: @PradeepSimha The question is the example.

Comment: @theSun `mat[i][n] = sum;` In this piece of code you are accessing `n`, which is out of bounds, since it's the size of the second dimension, maybe you mean `mat[i][n-1] = sum;`

Comment: Put the "mat[i][n-1] = sum;" and "mat[m-1][j] = sum;" outside the inner for loop and inside the outer for loop. Your question is not clear. However I provided information on the basis of whatever you have here.

Comment: @ripudam  I shall try both these methods right now. 1 second

Comment: @ripudam m-1 and n-1  have worked perfectly. Thanks yu very much. How can i mark you as correct answer?

Comment: What is the problem? Also did you see that I edited my comment?

Comment: @ripudam I saw the edit, and i used the edited code. it works perfectly now. thank you!

Comment: @Usar Yes I realized after you posted as question wasn't clear do I just didn't realize that.

Comment: @usar Your method works as well, Thank you very very much!!

Comment: @theSun Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @theSun Yes, at the beginning is very difficult not to do things wrong with the bounds of the arrays

Comment: @ripudam Yes it is, How can i mark your answer as the correct answer?
or increase your reputation?

Comment: I have added the suggestion as the answer. You can mark it as answer.

Comment: @usar Thanks to you I now know how to fix my future array problems So thanks a lot :D

Comment: Use a debugger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `mat[i][n-1] = sum;` and `mat[m-1][j] = sum;` outside the inner for loop and inside the outer for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop you should set the value of your sum after the loop and only once.
Something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
    sum += mat[i][j];
}
mat[i][n-1] = sum;//n-1
```

Comment: Please, notice that mat[i][n] goes out of bounds, so correct it with `mat[i][n-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the cells to contain the row and column sum are zero before summing.

Try

```
package com.example.matrix;

public class MatrixOperation {

    public void summatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int rows;
        int cols;

        rows = matrix.length;
        cols = matrix[0].length;
        // initialize sums
        for (int i=0; i < rows-1; i++) {
            matrix[i][cols-1] = 0;
        }
        for (int j=0; j < cols-1; j++) {
            matrix[rows-1][j] = 0;
        }

        for (int i=0; i < rows-1; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < cols-1; j++) {
                matrix[rows-1][j] = matrix[rows-1][j]+matrix[i][j];
                matrix[i][cols-1] = matrix[i][cols-1] + matrix[i][j];
            }
        }


        for (int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```